# IIS Rewrite url twice?

Tags: php, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have a url '/quote/details/e4dd5f4e4c705436ba381b0dc06fccc0' which rewrites to: '/quote/details/?retrieveQuote=e4dd5f4e4c705436ba381b0dc06fccc0'

```
<rule name="Rewrite Saved Quote to Query String Type" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="^quote/details/([^/]+)/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="quote/details/?retrieveQuote={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

This works because when i put stopProcessing to true i get a 404 with the correct output:
Requested URL      quote/details/?retrieveQuote=e4dd5f4e4c705436ba381b0dc06fccc0

This should now be rewritten like the rest of the site using this:

```
<rule name="Rewrite to Index" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/admin/+" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/api/+" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

But for some reason it doesn't and if i use the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] it prints: quote/details/e4dd5f4e4c705436ba381b0dc06fccc0 but should be: quote/details/?retrieveQuote=e4dd5f4e4c705436ba381b0dc06fccc0

Any ideas how to get it to work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any solution to this, so i created a routing rule and split the required parameter from the URL.